# Which case to use for JavaScript for naming variables?

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, naming-conventions

I am using PHP Laravel and MySQL (which uses snake_case for field names) for API.
Is it ok to use snake_case instead of camelCase for client side javascript so that it's easier to copy paste field names from PHP code to javascirpt code and when mapping javascript variables to PHP models?
Should I have used camelCase for MySQL data fields as well?

Thanks

Comment: The established naming convention in JS is camel case. When I see code written with snake-case, it looks like a bird would had walk all over the code, IMHO. You can use whatever you feel is good, unless your employer has some naming convention policy.

Answer (score 1):

Using snake_case in your MySQL fields will not affect the functionality of your application as long as you are careful with the mapping of the fields in your PHP models and your JavaScript code. Keep in mind that if you decide to use snake_case for your MySQL fields, you'll need to convert it to camelCase when working with javascript. This can be done using a library like change-case or writing a custom function.